# Dynamically convert flash content when played from iPad

Tags: ipad, video, video-streaming, html5-video, video-encoding

I have a website that uses flash player to stream videos.
I want to make the website content available from iPad.

Most of the video files are in the flash format.
As i understand, flash is not supported by iPad and html5-video can be used as an alternative. But for that all of the current flash videos on the server have to be converted to mp4 format.

Can these videos be dynamically converted to another format when taken from iPad?

or, Do i have to convert all the video to another format like mp4 and upload them again just for iPad?

or, Is there a way to use the flash videos itself to stream in iPad?

I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: `html5-video` is one of the tags you used. Look into that - it doesn't use flash and is supported on the iPad.

Comment: yes, but for that i need to convert the flash videos to mp4 format, right?
is there a way to stream the flash videos in ipad using any runtime conversion?

Comment: `Can these videos be dynamically converted to another format when taken from iPad?`, No